# Can't close() map in ChronicleMap

Tags: java, compiler-errors, chronicle-map

According to the documentation, it is good practice to close https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map/blob/master/docs/CM_Tutorial.adoc#close-chroniclemap

I can't, for some reason:

```
Map<String, String> lexicalizationGraph = ChronicleMap
                .of(String.class, String.class)
                .name("lexicalizations-chronicle-map")
                .constantKeySizeBySample("bn:14271053n")
                .averageValue("average size of value")
                .entries(1_000_000_000L)
                .createPersistedTo(file);
```

and then later:

```
lexicalizationGraph.close();
```

It gives me the following error:

```
symbol:   method close()
  location: variable lexicalizationGraph of type java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>
```

How do I close it?

Comment: What is the error type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `close` method is defined in `ChronicleMap`, not `Map`. To access it, you must define the variable as `ChronicleMap` (or explicitly cast it when you want to `close()`, but don't do that):

```java
ChronicleMap<String, String> lexicalizationGraph = ChronicleMap 
                .of(String.class, String.class)
                .name("lexicalizations-chronicle-map")
                .constantKeySizeBySample("bn:14271053n")
                .averageValue("average size of value")
                .entries(1_000_000_000L)
                .createPersistedTo(file);
```